# Mouseout on element grouping fires before leaving bounding area in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, events

I'm trying to add a `click` and `mouseout` handler to a group of circles and text. The click handler works fine, but the mouse out seems to fire even if I haven't left the `circleGroup` area (shown below).

**Note**: there are multiple of these circle groups which are added in a grid.

[image]

Here is the SVG as it appears in the browser:

[image]

The code to produce the circleGroup, containing an outer green-ish circle, an inner white circle, and a text element, is as follows:

```
let circleGroup = leftPanelGroup.append('g');

let outerCircle = circleGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .style('fill', color)
    .attr("r", 15);

let innerCircle = circleGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', '#fff')
    .attr("r", 7);

let text = circleGroup.append('text')
    .style('color', '#fff')
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y - 25)
    .style('fill', '#fff')
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr('id', 'circle-text')
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text('Thank you');

...
```

On `click` anywhere within the `circleGroup`, the `circleClick` should fire. This works fine. The issue is, the `circleMouseout` function seems to randomly fire even if I haven't yet left the bounding area of the `circleGroup`:

```
circleGroup.on('click', circleClick).on('mouseout', circleMouseout);

function circleClick() {
    // Do something
}
function circleMouseout() {
    // Do something else
}
```

The output HTML in console shows the area of the `<g>` svg group element. I'd expect that click anywhere in this highlighted area would fire the `click` event, and only when I mouse out of this highlighted area would the `mouseout` event fire. Again, the `click` works fine, the `mouseout` does not.

[image]

```
<g>
   <circle cx="252.99037499999997" cy="340.938" r="15" style="fill: rgb(108, 160, 123);"> 
   </circle>
   <circle cx="252.99037499999997" cy="340.938" r="7" style="fill: rgb(108, 160, 123); stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   </circle>
   <text x="252.99037499999997" y="315.938" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" id="circle-text" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-anchor: middle;">Thank you
   </text>
</g>
```

Comment: "The issue is, the circleMouseout function seems to randomly fire even if I haven't yet left the bounding area of the circleGroup" - this is the expected behavior (well, it shouldn't be random, it should be as soon as you move the mouse away from the circle and or text). The mouse only interacts with the drawn elements within the `g` (specifically, their stroke and/or fill if defined), not the `g`'s bounding box.

Comment: @AndrewReid so if I apply an event to the `g`, do all contained elements now have a bound event handler?

Comment: The event handler is still on the `g`, but the only way to mouseover a `g` is to mouseover a child element such as a text or circle element.

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks. I don't want the `mouseout` to fire, for example, when mousing out of the smaller contained elements like `text` and `innerCircle`. How can I prevent specific contained elements within `g` from firing? The use case here is that I want a help tooltip to popup on click, and fade out on mouse out. Mousing out from the contained smaller `text` element would be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounding box of a `g` doesn't affect where a mouse interacts with it.The mouse only interacts with the "interaction area" of an element. This is generally the stroke or fill of rendered elements. So, whenever your mouse leaves the circles or the text, you trigger the mouseout event, not when you leave the bounding box of the parent `g`.

If you want the bounding box of the parent `g` to interact with the mouse, then we need to add a new rectangle. We can extract the `g`'s bbox and use this to draw a new rectangle over the bounding box of the `g`. This rectangle can be given the fill of `none` to make it invisible, but also given a pointer-events property of all to ensure it interacts with the mouse:

```
let boundingBox = circleGroup.append('rect')
  .each(function() {
     var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();  // get parent `g` bounding box
     d3.select(this)
       .attr("width", bbox.width)           // size rect based on bounding box.
       .attr("height", bbox.height)
       .attr("x", bbox.x)
       .attr("y", bbox.y)
       .attr("fill","none")
       .attr("pointer-events","all")
  })
```

Now we can assign event listeners to the `g`, or the `rect` for that matter, and the entire `g` bounding box will respond to mouse events:

```js
let circleGroup = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g");

let x = 50;
let y = 50;
let color = "steelblue";

let outerCircle = circleGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .style('fill', color)
    .attr("r", 15);

let innerCircle = circleGroup.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', '#fff')
    .attr("r", 7);

let text = circleGroup.append('text')
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y - 25)
    .style('fill', color)
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr('id', 'circle-text')
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text('Thank you');

let boundingBox = circleGroup.append('rect')
  .each(function() {
     var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
     d3.select(this)
       .attr("width", bbox.width)
       .attr("height", bbox.height)
       .attr("x", bbox.x)
       .attr("y", bbox.y)
       .attr("fill","none")
       .attr("pointer-events","all")
  })

circleGroup.on("mouseover", function() {
     console.log("mouseover");
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
     console.log("mouseout");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use pointer-events, don't use fill=transparent.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I know you're the authority on SVG so I have already changed the answer, is there a quick reason you can share as to why pointer events is better?

Comment: because it's more efficient. Browsers have code specially for it whereas fill=transparent actually forces more of the rendering code to run pointlessly.